# Converting negative numbers to positive numbers but keeping positive numbers unchanged

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I want to apply a bitmask to a number that will mimic the absolute value function for 2's complement encoded signed 32 bit integers. So far, I have

```
int absoluteValue(int x) {
     int sign = x >> 31; //get most significant byte...all 1's if x is < 0, all 0's if x >= 0
     int negated = (~x + 1) & sign; //negates the number if negative, sets to 0 if positive
     //what should go here???
}
```

Am I going in the right direction? I'm not really sure where to go from here (mostly just how to apply a mask to keep the original positive value). I also don't want to use any conditional statements

Comment: Sorry, what is the language of your code, you tag both C and C++, can you remove one of these tag to clarify your question ?

Comment: `if(x < 0) { x = -x; }`. There is no guarantee that any system uses 2's complement.

Comment: I don't want to use conditional statements, so like no ifs, ternaries, etc

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: `if (x >> (sizeof x * CHAR_BIT - 1))` tells you if the number is negative for a signed value. (e.g. if the sign-bit is set) If it is negative, then `return (~x + 1)` otherwise just `return x`. (*remember -- only negative values are represented in 2's compliment, positive values are unchanged*)

Comment: Should negative numbers be made positive, or should they be negated? These goals are contradictory since there is a negative number whose negation is not positive

Comment: harold just negated, but you're right, this wouldn't work for INT_MIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part

```
negated = (~x + 1) & sign;
```

is wrong, you are going to get either 1 or 0, you have to create a mask with all
first 31 bits to 0 and only the last one to either 0 or 1.

Assuming that for you target you are dealing with 32 bit integers with 2
complement, you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// assuming 32bit, 2 complement
int sign_inverse(int n)
{
    int mask = ~n & 0x80000000U;

    if(n == 0)
        mask = 0;

    return (~n + 1) | mask;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = -4;
    int c = 54;
    int d = 0;

    printf("sign_inverse(%d) = %d\n", a, sign_inverse(a));
    printf("sign_inverse(%d) = %d\n", b, sign_inverse(b));
    printf("sign_inverse(%d) = %d\n", c, sign_inverse(c));
    printf("sign_inverse(%d) = %d\n", d, sign_inverse(d));

    return 0;
}
```

but you need at least 1 `if` for the case of 0, because the mask for 0 is `0x80000000`.

The output of this is:

```
$ ./b 
sign_inverse(5) = -5
sign_inverse(-4) = 4
sign_inverse(54) = -54
sign_inverse(0) = 0
```

Comment: @user1228123 the `&` is wrong in the positive case. In case the number is positive, the OP's `sign` variable is 0. Anything bitwise AND 0 is 0, it doesn't matter to what `(~x + 1)` is evaluated. If the number is negative then the result is implementation defined as the compiler might do an arithmetic shift.

Comment: Sorry Pablo, too hasty with my comment removal. It is correct because of the subtlety that right shifting a negative number puts a 1 in the most significant bit(s). Otherwise a negative number would change sign on its first right bit shift.

Comment: To be clearer, that means sign is either 0xFFFFFFFF or 0x00000000 (-1 or 0).

Comment: @user1228123 the positive case if definitively wrong, the negative case might be correct only if the compiler does the arithmetic shift.

Comment: negated is perhaps a misleading variable name, but as Howard Wang originally said it gives 0 for a positive x which is then handled appropriately by the (negated << 1) + x. I'll take your word for it about the negative x case, but is fine with GCC.

Answer (score 3):

Bizarre question. What about

```
return (negated << 1) + x;
```

So put together this makes:

```
int absoluteValue(int x) {
 int sign = x >> 31; //get most significant byte...all 1's if x is < 0, all 0's if x >= 0
 int negated = (~x + 1) & sign; //negates the number if negative, sets to 0 if positive
 return (negated << 1) + x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that two's complement representation is not guaranteed, and also the behaviour of operator `>>` on signed values, where the result get's "filled" with `1`-bits is implementation defined (cf., for example, [cppreference.com/arithmetic operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic)):

> For negative LHS, the value of LHS >> RHS is implementation-defined
>   where in most implementations, this performs arithmetic right shift
>   (so that the result remains negative). Thus in most implementations,
>   right shifting a signed LHS fills the new higher-order bits with the
>   original sign bit (i.e. with 0 if it was non-negative and 1 if it was
>   negative).

But if you take this for given, and if you just want to use bit wise operations and operator `+`, you are already going into the right direction.

The only thing is that you should take into account the mask you create ( i.e. your `sign`) in that you toggle the bits of `x` only in the case where `x` is negative. You can achieve this by the XOR-operator as follows:

```
int x = -3000;
unsigned int mask = x >> 31;
int sign = mask & 0x01;

int positive = (x^mask) + sign;

printf("x:%d  mask:%0X  sign:%d  positive:%d\n",x,mask,sign,positive);
```